Thingsboard in dashboards map widget is not working properly
undefined resize 
The map widget does not getting it own gobal varible resize . It is inbuilt Thingsboard widget. Also if we refresh it then it starts to work , otherwise it gives same error of undefined .
I think it is the issue of load the widget is not load properly . Please help me to solve this issue.
I tried reload the page and it started to work but it . we need to reload the page . Need some permanent solution.

Do you see any errors in the browser web console (developer tools)?
